# Function return discarding changes

Tags: python

So I have a file, `main.py`. The contents are such:

```
var = 0

def func():
    var = 1

def pr():
    func()
    print(var)

pr()
```

When run, this prints out `0` instead of my expected `1`. Why and how can I get the changes in `func()` to stick?

Comment: You're facing a `scope` problem... Take a look here, it may be useful for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/291978/short-description-of-python-scoping-rules

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do it like this by refering to var as a global in func():

```
var = 0

def func():
    global var
    var = 1

def pr():
    func()
    print(var)

pr()
```

Comment: One forgets things from time to time ;-) Glad I could help.